# Mutable variable is accessible from closure in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably "double-posted". But I am not able to assign the solutions to my problem.

I have 6 fileupload input fields. Whenever they change, I wanna alert "Changed!".
I want to iterate through thoes 6 fileupload id's with a for-loop.
Now, it gives me the error on variable i "Mutable variable is accessible from closure". I saw some solutions for this. But I'm not able to use these solutions for my problem.

```
function fileUploadCheck() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("#SOMEID"+i).change(function () {
                alert('changed!');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not quote document, just use `$(document)`. You don't need DOM ready inside your function.

Comment: Remove `$("document").ready(function () {` you don't need that in your loop. Read http://api.jquery.com/ready/. Just wondering why don't you use common class to bind event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses [implicit iteration](https://api.jquery.com/each/). You don't have to loop manually.

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event) {
  // check your console to see the value of `this`
  console.log(this, "changed");
});
```

---

From the [jQuery .each docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Note: most jQuery methods that return a jQuery object also loop through the set of elements in the jQuery collection — a process known as *implicit iteration*. When this occurs, it is often unnecessary to *explicitly* iterate with the `.each()` method:

```
// The .each() method is unnecessary here:
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "foo" );
});

// Instead, you should rely on implicit iteration:
$( "li" ).addClass( "bar" );
```

---

Regarding your "Mutable variable is accesible from closure", see this simplified example

```
for (var i=1; i<=6; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}

// 777777
// ALL SEVENS? WTF
```

The reason for that is, the closure depends on `i`, but `i` is changing outside of the closure. By the time any function is run, `i` has already set to `7`, so the logged output for each function is `7`.

If you use the method I have above, you won't have to worry about this at all. If you are still curious how you would fix this, please see

```
for (var i=1, fn; i<=6; i++) {

  fn = (function(n) {
    console.log(n);
  })(i);

  setTimeout(fn, 100);
}

// 123456
// YAY
```

Now each function is properly "bound" with an immutable `i` input; meaning the value of `i` will not change inside of the closure-wrapped function. Check out [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you're interested in shortcuts **^.^**

Comment: Also add about `this` in event handler

Comment: Tho i have a question, what is this "Mutable variable is accesible from closure" How can I avoid that/what kind of error is this?

Comment: May be worth mentioning that using `Function.prototype.bind` is about 2/3 slower than wrapping the body of the loop in another, anonymous function which closes over `i`. See the test here http://jsperf.com/extra-closure-vs-bind.

Comment: @igorraush, sure, it's worth mentioning. Xatenev, if you're using `.bind` in a high-volume area of your code, you might want to consider optimizing it.